# Want to split user name in django-nonrel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

In my django-nonrel project,all usernames are joined with '_'(underscore). For example, if username is 'guest_test' then I want to split guest and test seperate.I am trying with the following code:

```
CurrentUser=request.user
myuser=CurrentUser.split('_')
username=myuser.pop(0)
institute=myuser.pop(0)
print username
```

But its giving error as:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

How to do it?

Comment: split function is a BIF of str. that's why it's throwing error. so you need to convert your object to str

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing [the `User` object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#users) which has lots of attributes with the `username` which is one of those attributes.

`CurrentUser` contains a `User` object, so you need to get the `username` of this `User` to then do the `split` on.  Try:

```
institute,username = CurrentUser.username.split('_')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a split function on the user object which is meant only for string object. You can do a type cast like this .

```
CurrentUser=str(request.user)
```